# Is my question on-topic if it can't be replicated?

Tags: support

I have a question, but I can't reproduce the issue outside of my project. This means that I can't post any code to show the failure, but I can explain the issue clearly. Will this be considered on or off topic?

As a side note, is asking off-topic questions (I don't mean obviously off-topic, but where it's a grey area) bad, or should we just ask anyway? I guess that's why there is a voting system or is it best to ask on Meta first (makes my question here a waste of time, but people value the votes and I don't want lots of downvotes)?

Answer (score 8):

> I can't reproduce the issue outside of my project ... Will this be considered on or off topic?

There's a reason the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is often highlighted - if other people can't replicate it, it can be extremely difficult to figure out what is causing it. That's not to say that questions without one are automatically off-topic, and without more information about *why* you can't provide one it's hard to say whether your particular case is or not, but I would say that an inability to replicate the issue indicates that you need to do more work yourself first.

---

> where it's a grey area, should we just ask any way?

I would suggest using Meta or Chat to figure out whether or not it's on-topic if you're unsure, rather than just dumping it on the site anyway.